# OpenGL on CustomROM does not work

Tags: android, opengl-es

At the moment I'm writing a simple OpenGL game for Android. Today I moved a lot of matrix math to the GPU because it is much faster then the CPU. Before I did this all works great but now if I run my application the rendered scene looks like this:

[image]

The red Line should be a cube. The strange thing is that it only looks on my phone like this. I tested it on three other devices and there it worked great. All these other device run on the manufacturer stock ROM and on my phone I have installed a CustomROM (SlimKat). Is it possible that this is the reason why the output on my phone is so strange? I do not do any complex calculations in my shaders. My VertexShader code looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;

attribute vec4 aPosition;

void main()
{
    mat4 VM_Matrix  = uProjectionMatrix * uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix;    
    gl_Position = VM_Matrix * aPosition;
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this or do maybe you can delimit the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake after searching whole days in all files of my project. The reason why the screen looks like this was that while I have moved the matrix operations I commented some code out amongst other things:

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Really, really stupid but now I have found it and I hope I will learn from it. So no driver error and all works great now. The final question I have to you is why it worked normal on other (stock ROM) devices. Can manufacturers set a bit or provide some code to their drivers so that this line is called automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a driver issue. Custom ROMs may contain wrong drivers, especially if the android version of the custom ROM is higher then the latest version of stock ROM. Hardware abstraction layer has changed over the time and sometimes the "ROM cooks" don't have the updated drivers.

Just a question - are you sure this is faster? On the CPU you have to multiply the matrices only once per object (and the multiplication `ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix` is performed only once per frame). On the GPU you do the multiplication once per EVERY vertex.

Comment: Thank you for that. The strangest thing is that it worked before I have moved all the matrix multiplications to the shader. But if I roll it back it does not work anymore with the old code too... So I do not really believe that it is the custom ROM which casts the error but I have no other idea for this phenomenom

Comment: To your question I discused this [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/93435/36051) maybe this helps you. But I'm also not convinced that it is faster but I do not know much about GPUs so I believe the author.